# How can I improve a invoice capture and upload?

Tags: mobile, user-expectation, layout, input

I'm creating the UX for an Invoice capture/upload to translate to text feature in a mobile application.

The journey that I have for now is:

1. User taps on "Invoice Upload"
2. Pop up with "Application wants to user your camera" Cancel or Continue
3. If continue, it opens up the phone camera
4. Captures photo and uploads to "Invoice Upload" modal

On state 3, I would like for the user to have an overlay of an outline - so they dont cut off important information of the invoice, just like a bank's mobile check deposit feature.

I am trying to find UX patterns for bank deposits and how it works and the why for some ideas for the outline.

How can I make the outline or a better experience for the invoices capture?

Comment: Is the image capture simply a record for referring to at a later date or are you expecting to do OCR processing with it?

Answer (score 1):

**How can I make the outline or a better experience for the invoices capture?**

I know for instance that an eID card has an MRZ (Machine Readable Zone) that contains the necessary information of the holder. I have experience with mobile capture SDK made by MITEK systems. It simply scans the outlines of your eID card and then it will read out the MRZ. Mitek Systems is a company that is specialized in mobile capture and identity verification. You could have a look at their website, maybe they have a solution for capturing invoices.

https://www.miteksystems.com/

**My personal opinion on user experience with invoices**

My personal opinion on a digital approach with invoices would be having some sort of barcode/QR code which is generated when the invoice is officially created. The barcode/QR code would hold the necessary information that is needed to complete a request. It would be handy if I could scan that barcode/QR code with my banking app on my phone so I can easily pay the invoice directly on my phone.

For instance with banking you can setup on your banking app on your mobile phone:

- How much cash you want to withdraw
- On which personal account you want to withdraw the cash from

Next step will be verification with fingerscan on your phone and it would then open up the camera on your phone. When you are at the ATM, you just need to tap the screen in which it will show a QR code that you can scan with the camera of your phone. 
After that the ATM will recognize your request and will handle it. The requested amount of cash will come out of the ATM for you to collect.

Answer (score 0):

**I am trying to find UX patterns for bank deposits and how it works and the why for some ideas for the outline.**

I have used many applications and haven't seen any standard outline. NetVerify and other companies have online scanners of drivers licenses. Banks have it for check deposits. "My Fitness Pal" for bar codes on food packaging.

Ultimately, as important as standards are, what counts will be ease of use. Will a user see if the attempted photo is within the outline? Will he get feedback regarding glare, lighting levels, motion blur so that he knows if the photo is good?

For the user t's a binary experience. The type of outline is less important than the user knowing that there will be an outline; that the invoice must be inside the outline and that the submission was successful.